# Unity question about tilemap

Tags: unity, c#, tilemap

So if I planning to make big location like for example Stardew Valley with tile size 32x32, should I make all map and just have it, or should I load tiles as player moves to them. I actually new to this and I don't know what is real solution of this

Comment: Sounds like you should make a test map and profile the performance on your target hardware, and evaluate whether a single map is sufficient for your needs, or if the extra complexity of level streaming is required to meet your goals. This is the only way to know for sure, as Internet strangers like us do not have access to your build, nor deeply understand your plans and goals the way you do.

Comment: I don't think the map in Stardew Valley is big enough to use streaming map. You can directly load the entire map first, and then iterate if you encounter performance bottlenecks.

Comment: Related question: [What is the size limit to the Unity 2017.2 Tilemap?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/151048/what-is-the-size-limit-to-the-unity-2017-2-tilemap)